# How to check the number of executed operations in the past x minutes in Python?

Tags: python, performance, time

For example:

```
for i range(1,9999):
    #foo() is an operation that has varying execution time.
    foo(i);
    check_number_of_foo_executed_last_60_sec();
```

In the middle of the for loop, how to check how many `foo()` has been executed in, say last 60 seconds?

Apart from storing the time that each `foo()` was executed in a list, are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

### A smart way Python can re-use is the `signal.SIGALRM` for this :

The greatest thing on this is, that it
- requires zero changes in source code
and
- works even during "blocking" calculations:

I use it for even a process-level context-switches ( and stolen-CPU-time some platforms secretly throttle down ) monitoring, communicating over sockets with external process-Monitoring platform, even if GIL would not permit such "interleaved" operations ( during heavy **`numpy`**-processing that does not like to look around itself in high-steam number-crunching )

```
########################################################################
### SIGALRM_handler_          
###
def SIGALRM_handler_ConstTIME( aSigNUM, aFRAME ):
    try:
         global i
         print( "INF:: {0: >6d}x".format( i ) )
    except:
         pass
```

---

```
##########
# FINALLY:
# 
signal.signal(    signal.SIGALRM, SIGALRM_handler_ConstTIME )   # .ASSOC { SIGALRM: thisHandler }
signal.setitimer( signal.ITIMER_REAL, 60, 60 )                  # .SET   @60 [sec] interval, after first run, starting after 60[sec] initial-delay

...
INF::     28x
INF::     62x
INF::     97x
...

signal.setitimer( signal.ITIMER_REAL,  0, 5 )                   # .UNSET 
#############################################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading

count = 0
timer = None
try:
    def print_count():
        global timer
        timer = threading.Timer(5.0, print_count)
        timer.start()
        print count

    print_count()

    for i in range(1,9999):
        foo(i)
        count += 1
finally:
    if timer is not None:
        timer.cancel()
```